# Close the creation of a new .gitignore file in Git Bash

Tags: vi

I am trying to upload a Unity project to GitHub and I want to create a new `.gitignore` file. The instructions I am following suggest to create it using the `vi .gitignore` command, and to close the creation process, I have to type `:wq` at the end of the text. I typed the script and ended it with `:wq`, but it is not closing.

Comment: So this question has nothing to do with git, unity game engine, github, or git bash — it's about `vi`? In that case all of your tags are wrong; you should delete all of them and put `vi` instead. But if you find `vi` problematic, just don't use it. `.gitignore` is just a text file; any text editor will do. Use something you're comfortable with.

Comment: @matt I changed the tags, thank you for the info. And I will try and do the text file method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hit escape then ':' then write "wq" and hit enter